# UWP/c++-cx - Moving a button on the vertical axis by dragging it

Tags: xaml, button, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I have a Grid which is as high as the application and has the width of 50. I have got a button in it on the left top with the width of 50 also. I want to move this button along the vertical left axis by dragging it with the mouse. But it should be stil able to be clicked normally. I tried to do this with the drag-and-drop sample by microsoft but the procedure I want to implement is not quite drag-and-drop. How can I implement this by using XAML and c++-cx as code behind in an universal windows app ?

My XAML-Code for the Grid/Button:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Width="50" >
<Button x:Name="btnMove"  Content="Move me!" Background="PaleGreen" Click="btnMove_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" Height="50"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your requirement, you could move the button on the vertical axis by using [`ManipulationDelta`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.manipulationdelta) class. And you could achieve it with the following code.
For more please refer to [Handle pointer input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/handle-pointer-input). Here is [official code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicInput) sample.

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitManipulationTransforms();
    btnMove->ManipulationDelta += ref new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(this, &MainPage::btnMove_ManipulationDelta);
    btnMove->ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes::TranslateX;
}

void App14::MainPage::InitManipulationTransforms()
{
    transforms = ref new TransformGroup();
    previousTransform = ref new MatrixTransform();
    previousTransform->Matrix = Matrix::Identity;

    deltaTransform = ref new CompositeTransform();

    transforms->Children->Append(previousTransform);
    transforms->Children->Append(deltaTransform);

    // Set the render transform on the rect
    btnMove->RenderTransform = transforms;
}

void App14::MainPage::btnMove_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{

}
void MainPage::btnMove_ManipulationDelta(Platform::Object^ sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{


    previousTransform->Matrix = transforms->Value;

    // Get center point for rotation
    Point center = previousTransform->TransformPoint(Point(e->Position.X, e->Position.Y));
    deltaTransform->CenterX = center.X;
    deltaTransform->CenterY = center.Y;

    // Look at the Delta property of the ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs to retrieve
    // the rotation, scale, X, and Y changes
    deltaTransform->Rotation = e->Delta.Rotation;
    deltaTransform->TranslateX = e->Delta.Translation.X;
    deltaTransform->TranslateY = e->Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

You could change the scrolling direction of the button by modifying the `ManipulationMode` of button.

```
btnMove->ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes::TranslateY;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working fine. But I still got one question. With this code the button can get out of the appborders and then you cannot get him back, he stucks behind the border. How do I fix this ? How do I set borders ?

Comment: ´double height =(dynamic_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame^>(Window::Current->Content))->ActualHeight; ´
I declared the current height of the Frame, where exactly in the code do I place the if structure you posted before ?